# Define PHP-Function in XSL and calling it. Possible? How?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, transformation

Like the title tells: Is it possible to write a PHP-Function in a XSL-Document and call it afterwards?

I have no case, where I wanna do that. Its just a thing it came into my mind while learning XSL.

In XSL you can compose something like:

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
   ...some php...
</xsl>
```

The PHP code will be run in your rendered page. Is it possible to create e.g. a PHP Function in the processing-instruction and call it later (in the same template)?

Pseudo-Sample:

```
<xsl:template>

   <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">
      ...some php processing $foo...
   </xsl>

   <xsl:variable name="foo" select="xpath/node">

   <xsl:value-of select="call-php-function-with-$foo"/>

</xsl>
```

I'm looking forward to your solutions/approaches :)

Chris

Comment: If you are using XSL for template, I would suggest you to use Smarty instead. It has better performance and you can execute PHP in the template. http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: This doesen't really help us discussing this topic. It's about XSLT. I don't know smarty, but like I see on first impression, it's something complete different. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for explanation and possible alternative solutions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**In XSLT 1.0** it is not possible to call functions written in another language, unless these are written following the requirements of the particular XSLT processor for *extension functions* and specified in the set of available extension functions at the time the transformation is to be initiated.

Functions can be simulated by calling or applying templates.

**In XSLT 2.0** it is possible to write functions *in XSLT* using the **[`<xsl:function>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#stylesheet-functions)** instruction. These functions can then be referenced in any XPath expression that is specified in the `select` attribute of any other XSLT instructions.

**Both in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0** it is even possible to implement *higher-order functions* (HOF). This is what the **[FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net)** (written entirely in XSLT) does.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon: Yes, your comment confirms what you find as strange in this answer -- the `php:function()` is an *extension function* and it isn't written in XSLT itself.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong - you yourself admit that one can use extension functions. It can be done in PHP too. For reference, I have given a couple of pointers in a separate answer below.

Comment: Ah sorry @Dimitre Novatches, didn't realize you had repolied, was rewriting my comment. I think that's being unnecessarily pedantic - ChrisBenyamin just wanted to use some PHP function in his XSLT, I don't think he cares whether they are extension or not.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon: This answer clearly says that invoking extension functions (functions written in another PL) is possible, provided "*these are written following the requirements of the particular XSLT processor for extension functions*". There is nothing wrong with the answer and it was found so satisfactory that it was accepted.

Comment: Well I think it's wrong because it gives pointers to FXSL rather then  the to the documentation on writing PHP extensions, which is what he asked for. Anyhow, I have added those links should someone else stumble on this.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon: This is an XSLT answer, not a PHP one. Do look at one of the comments by the OP -- he says about his question: " It's about XSLT".

Answer (score 4):

I think the selected answer is pointing in the wrong direction. No need to use FXSL, you CAN easily add extensions written in other languages to XSLT - for example Jython or Javascript with Xalan, Java with most Java processors, etc.

As for PHP, if you are doing the XSLT processing in a PHP script (as opposed to, say, Xalan run from Ant or something) then it is very easy  to use XSLTProcessor::registerPHPFunctions which allows you to write things like

```
$xsl = <<<EOF
...
<xsl:value-of select="php:function('myFunc', . )"/> 
...
EOF;

function myFunc( $node ) {
//etc
```

Of course, only a PHP script would then be able to process the XSL correctly.

It's all quite clearly documented at 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php

Comment: fritzfromlondon: You need to read the selected answer well -- in fact it says that it is possible to write such functions, provided this complies with the rules for writing extension functions. Please, edit your answer and remove the incorrect statement in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done (bear in mind Dimitre that if he's asking about PHP he's almost certainly limited to XSLT 1.0, and FXSL isn't quite what he's after).

Firstly, if are planning to write the PHP yourself, and use it as part of a document processing flow, it's probably a bad choice of language for this. In the case where you just want to expand the functionality of XSL a tiny bit with a few PHP functions of your own or useful library functions like preg_replace, so you can call them from your XSLT, you're absolutely fine if you know what those are beforehand: you export the PHP functions to the XSLT and just call them from there.

If the code you want to execute is different for each document though, it gets harder (ie, for processing instructions in the documents you are trying to process which contain PHP, and you want the XSLT script when evaluating your document to execute the processing instructions). Try and factor out the functions into a known set and just call them from the PHP, but if you can't and still want to try, it's down to hackery.

(I am assuming you know about PHP's way of exporting functions to XSLT: you make some ordinary PHP functions, you export them to the XSLT script using registerPHPFunctions, and them just call them as functions inside the XSLT. That's a well-trodden path; check the docs.)

Back to executing PHP code in your document's PIs from an XSLT script.

(Not done myself, but shouldn't be all that hard to implement.) It is not possible to do it in one pass, I believe. You have to call the XSLT processor, and whenever you hit the PHP you want to run, put in a marker tag (eg `<phpmarker md5ofcode="php:md5(...)">`) and pass the code back up to the calling PHP. Hacky, but potentially liveable-with would be to put it in an xsl:message and catch it from a custom handler in PHP.

When the first run has ended, do a bit of string manipulation to make a wrapper function around each block of code you grabbed, eval that string to create the functions, export them to XSLT engine, and then re-call with a second XSLT script which will cat the marker nodes, and call the PHP on their contents.

Ugly? Yes. You might want to explain why you would want it, but it should be possible (in two passes) to get it to work.

**Edit**: Having reread your question a few more times, I'm increasing confused. Are you sure you want to PIs *in your XSLT*? PIs go in the documents, explaining how they are to be processed. If the PHP is meant to be going in the XSLT file and that's not a typo, I think you might be a bit confused, and it's just a plain vanilla application of PHP's registerPHPFunctions. You just have to put the PHP in a separate file and call it from the XSLT, which isn't a huge burden considering XSLT scripts don't have to contain much functionality before they're big enough to split into two files.

Comment: Nicholas Wilson, I see your confusion. 1). In XSLT 1.0 one cannot write *functions* (written in XSLT). In XSLT 2.0 and up there is such capability, using the `xsl:function` instruction; 2) FXSL has versions *both* for XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. In my answer I mention that the OP can use FXSL (as anyone else, who is using XSLT 1.0).